# Win XP, Win 8 and Linux in Grub2

Tags: linux, windows-8, windows-xp, multi-boot, grub2

For the following setup:

```
kellogs@kellogs-PC:~ > sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for kellogs: 
omitting empty partition (5)

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160040803840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312579695 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x48424841

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   201358709   100679323+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       201358710   312576704    55608997+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       201358773   222243209    10442218+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6       222243273   310488254    44122491   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       310488318   312576685     1044184   82  Linux swap / Solaris
omitting empty partition (5)

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
16 heads, 63 sectors/track, 969021 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7b444a5b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   339968159   169984048+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       339968160   667647791   163839816    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       680857693   976772334   147957321    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb4       667648000   680857599     6604800   83  Linux
/dev/sdb5       680857695   735038639    27090472+  af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sdb6       735038703   976772334   120866816    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

there are these OSes

Linux : sda5

Win XP : sda1

Win 8 (latest addition) : sdb6

The story
**before adding Win 8** There was Grub2 happily booting into linux / Win XP
**after adding Win 8** Win 8 grabbed the MBR and deployed its own bootloader into that one. I was able to boot Win 8 / Win XP but not Linux any longer.
**what I did** Reinstalled Grub2 to MBR, of course :) enabling me to boot into Linux / Win8, but not  WinXP
**what next** Attempted:
http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Chain_002dloading
and
http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#DOS_002fWindows

These attempts did put a Win XP entry in Grub2 boot options,but it mingled them Windowses! 
Booting the  **Win8** boot menu entry would start either WinXP or Win8 randomly
Same for the **WinXP** boot menu entry

How would I get my WinXP back ?
Thanks!

LE:

> Booting the  **Win8** boot menu entry would start either WinXP or Win8
>   randomly

Actually, it might not be the case. Win 8 has this feature of "Starting earlier Windows version" which did boot Win XP OK prior to having had the MBR rewritten with Grub2. 
Afterwards, instead of immediately launching WinXP, it seems this feature will reboot computer (BIOS POST), and then Selecting again the **Win 8** entry from grub resumes the Win XP boot. Odd, will update if I find this behaviour consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what I have added in later edit holds. See the LE again below

---

> Booting the **Win8** boot menu entry would start either WinXP or Win8
>   randomly

Actually, it might not be the case. Win 8 has this feature of "Starting earlier Windows version" which did boot Win XP OK prior to having had the MBR rewritten with Grub2. Afterwards, instead of immediately launching WinXP, it seems this feature will reboot computer (BIOS POST), and then Selecting again the **Win 8** entry from grub resumes the Win XP boot. Odd, will update if I find this behaviour consistent.